# T - matching network design

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, impedance, passive-networks, impedance-matching

can you help me on understanding the procedure to design this T - matching network?

My aim is that of transforming a resistive load R to a complex value R'', while R' indicates an intermediate value.

[image]

By the classical transformation formulas with Q-factor we get the following *transformation ratio*:

[image]

where:

[image]

and

[image]

**First question**: According to the previous picture, Q2 is the Q factor of the network made of B3 and R''. But if we look at the transformation ratio, Q2 seems the quality factor of the network made of the global network made of X2 and B1//R. So I do not understand this step.

**Second question:** is the fact that we see R' at right and at left imposed by us? Or is it determined by other factors?

[image]

**Third question:** why is Qmax = 2 Q and approximation?

[image]

**Fourth question**: which is the procedure if our load is always resistive (R) but we want to see a complex impedance Z'' at left?

Comment: This is a procedure for 1 frequency and variable Q. But don’t you want to define Zin as a complex impedance over a wide range of frequencies ? Including Q...

Comment: In general yes, but I have some doubts also on understanding the procedure for getting a resistive load R'' for a single frequency

Comment: I have never used this method. I start with specs for Zin(f), Zout (f) besides this is a Pi network which may not be appropriate